# SQL pivot 1:M rows into string columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a 1:M recordset that I need to pivot into columns where the results are concatenated.

Create sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable 
(
    ID int,
    Division int,
    Material int
);

 insert into #temptable
 Values
 (999, 1, 1)
 ,(999, 1, 2)
 ,(999, 1, 3)
 ,(999, 2, 1)
 ,(999, 2, 6)
 ,(999, 3, 2)
```

Sample data:

```
ID     Division     Material   
----  ----------   ----------   
999       1            1          
999       1            2
999       1            3
999       2            1
999       2            6
999       3            2
```

I need the results to look like this, where the materials for each division are concatenated:

```
 ID   Division-1   Division-2   Division-3
----  ----------   ----------   ----------
999     1,2,3          1,6          2
```

Comment: did you try any thing ?

Comment: And what version of SQL?

Comment: Kamran's answer below solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT ID,
       [1] AS 'Division-1',
       [2] AS 'Division-2',
       [3] AS 'Division-3'
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           a.ID,
           a.Division,
           LEFT(r.ResourceName, LEN(r.ResourceName) - 1) ResourceName
    FROM #temptable a
         CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT CAST(Material AS VARCHAR(10))+','
        FROM #temptable t
        WHERE a.[ID] = t.[ID]
              AND a.Division = t.Division
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) r(ResourceName)
) src PIVOT(MAX(ResourceName) FOR Division IN([1],
                                              [2],
                                              [3])) piv;
```

**brief explanation**
We need to create pivot over comma separated structure.

Below query converts column value into comma separated rows.

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.Division,
       LEFT(r.ResourceName, LEN(r.ResourceName) - 1) ResourceName
FROM #temptable a
     CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(Material AS VARCHAR(10))+','
    FROM #temptable t
    WHERE a.[ID] = t.[ID]
          AND a.Division = t.Division
    FOR XML PATH('')
) r(ResourceName);
```

After that we create pivot over it.

Comment: This is excellent, way beyond my kung-fu level.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @ScottM : If it helped, mark it as answer in case people stumble upon